# What drove the adoption of 64-bit instruction sets?

Tags: cpu, history

In the 2000s 64-bit ISAs displace 32-bit architectures. Intel tried and failed to make [IA-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-64) and AMD won with its [x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64). 64-bit was important.

Why did 64-bit ISA displace 32-bit ISAs? How were they lacking.

What "killer" application that drove their adoption?

Comment: This is largely an opinion question, but 48-bit first in AS-400 followed by 64-bit in Workstation and Servers allows more memory for operating systems and software. Try running BIG apps on a 32-bit system.

Comment: IA-64 failed because it was incompatible with x86-64 software.

Comment: FWIW, your “Clarified question.” is not better. This is still very opinion-based. This is not the appropriate kind of question for this forum. This is better suited for places like Quora or ArsTechnica forums that are open-ended chat forums.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It was history+hardware, and the seemed like the most suitable SX site. I will try to ask it in a manner which allows for a better answers.

Comment: There was never any "killer app", it was just years of edging towards the limits of 32-bit until the change became more and more necessary and the various band-aids and workarounds became unwieldy. After that it was years and years of dealing with the fallout from the change. The change was not sudden, nor was it particularly easy. Many people had outdated hardware or legacy devices they could not or would not let go of. It is similar to the current changeover to Windows 11 where Microsoft basically obsoleted any PCs older than 5 years and many people simply can not upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify IA64 was join project of Intel and HP. And it support full set of PA-RISC instructions.

Probably one of the main reason was disks, filesystems and big files. I do not say it is impossible 32bit processor to manage filesystems and files bigger than 4TB but this will involve good amount of additional operations to address so big space and files. There was examples (about the memory) in form of PAX extension, but as far as I know, only Oracle RDBMS can use it on x86 32bit.

Additionally Intel concentrate the manufacturing only in the server area so it appear discrepancy/incompatinility between 32bit desktops and 64bit servers. Also IA64 architecture is not compatible with x86.